# Windirstat/TreeSizeFree showing incorrect disk space compared to Windows

Tags: windows, disk

Windows says the disk is at 160 GB used.

WinDirStat and TreeSizeFree say 90 GB.

I have no idea where the discrepancy is from.

I've checked this thread: https://superuser.com/questions/917110/why-does-windirstat-report-less-space-used-than-windows-does?noredirect=1&lq=1&newreg=459190bfe2a3407f8010b3e5cc070fd4.

Running as admin doesn't change anything. Also I've checked my recovery/restore options, and I've only allotted 18 GB, of which only 5.5% is being used, and windirstat/treesizefree take this into account.

Answer (score 0):

I ran space sniffer as admin, and it found the hidden folder windirstat could not.
40 GB of log files in c:\windows\system32\winevt\logs.  Maybe I will just check archived event logs folder next time.  Its huge, and its hidden.